# Spring-MVC, Hibernate : Creating DTO objects from Domain objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, dto

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am trying to search for List of GroupNotes in database. The mapping in my project is GroupCanvas has one-to-many mapping with GroupSection and GroupSection has one-to-many mapping with GroupNotes. Because of these mappings, I was getting LazyInitializationException. As suggested on SO, I should be converting the objects to a DTO objects for transfer. I checked on net, but couldnt find a suitable way to translate those.

I have just created a new List to avoid the error, but one field is still giving me an error. I would appreciate if anyone tells me either how to fix this error or convert the objects to a DTO objects so they can be transferred.

Controller code :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/findgroupnotes/{days}/{canvasid}")
    public @ResponseBody List<GroupNotes> findGroupNotesByDays(@PathVariable("days")int days, @PathVariable("canvasid")int canvasid){
        List<GroupNotes> groupNotesList = this.groupNotesService.findGroupNotesByDays(days,canvasid);

        List<GroupNotes> toSendList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(GroupNotes groupNotes : groupNotesList){
            GroupNotes toSendNotes = new GroupNotes();
            toSendNotes.setMnotecolor(groupNotes.getMnotecolor());
            toSendNotes.setNoteCreationTime(groupNotes.getNoteCreationTime());
            toSendNotes.setMnotetag(groupNotes.getMnotetag());
            toSendNotes.setMnotetext(groupNotes.getMnotetext());
            toSendNotes.setAttachCount(groupNotes.getAttachCount());
            toSendNotes.setNoteDate(groupNotes.getNoteDate());
            toSendList.add(toSendNotes);
        }
        return toSendList;

    }
```

GroupNotesDAOImpl :

```
 @Override
    public List<GroupNotes> searchNotesByDays(int days, int mcanvasid) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -days);
        long daysAgo = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        Timestamp nowMinusDaysAsTimestamp = new Timestamp(daysAgo);
        GroupCanvas groupCanvas = (GroupCanvas) session.get(GroupCanvas.class,mcanvasid);
        Query query = session.createQuery("from GroupSection as n where n.currentcanvas.mcanvasid=:mcanvasid");
        query.setParameter("mcanvasid", mcanvasid);

        List<GroupSection> sectionList = query.list();
        List<GroupNotes> notesList = new ArrayList<GroupNotes>();
        for (GroupSection e : sectionList) {
            System.out.println("Section name is "+e.getMsectionname());
            GroupSection groupSection = (GroupSection) session.get(GroupSection.class,e.getMsectionid());
            Query query1 = session.createQuery("from GroupNotes as gn where gn.ownednotes.msectionid=:msectionid and gn.noteCreationTime >:limit");
            query1.setParameter("limit", nowMinusDaysAsTimestamp);
            query1.setParameter("msectionid",e.getMsectionid());
            notesList.addAll(query1.list());
        }
// I am getting the data below, but I get JSON errors.
        for(GroupNotes groupNotes : notesList){
            System.out.println("Group notes found are "+groupNotes.getMnotetext());
        }
        return notesList;
    }
```

GroupCanvas model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "membercanvas")
public class GroupCanvas{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "currentcanvas",fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<GroupSection> ownedsection = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<GroupSection> getOwnedsection() {
        return this.ownedsection;
    }

    public void setOwnedsection(Set<GroupSection> ownedsection) {
        this.ownedsection = ownedsection;
    }
}
```

GroupSection model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "membersection")
public class GroupSection{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ownednotes", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<GroupNotes> sectionsnotes = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<GroupNotes> getSectionsnotes(){
        return this.sectionsnotes;
    }

    public void setSectionsnotes(Set<GroupNotes> sectionsnotes){
        this.sectionsnotes=sectionsnotes;
    }
}
```

GroupNotes model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupnotes")
public class GroupNotes{

    @Id
    @Column(name="mnoteid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "mnote_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mnote_gen",sequenceName = "mnote_seq")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "mnoticesidindex")
    private int mnoticesid;

    @Column(name = "mnotetext")
    private String mnotetext;

    @Column(name = "mnoteheadline")
    private String mnotetag;

    @Column(name = "mnotecolor")
    private String mnotecolor;

    @Column(name = "mnoteorder")
    private double mnoteorder;

    @Column(name = "attachmentcount")
    private int attachCount;

    @Column(name = "notedate")
    private String noteDate;

    @Column(name = "uploader")
    private String uploader;

    @Column(name = "activeedit")
    private boolean activeEdit;

    @Column(name = "notedisabled")
    private boolean noteDisabled;

    @Column(name = "noteinactive")
    private boolean noteInActive;

    @Column(name = "notecreatoremail")
    private String noteCreatorEmail;

    @Column(name = "prefix")
    private String prefix;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private Timestamp noteCreationTime;

    @Transient
    private boolean notRead;

    @Transient
    private String tempNote;

    @Transient
    private String canvasUrl;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "msectionid")
    @JsonIgnore
    private GroupSection ownednotes;

    @JsonIgnore
    public GroupSection getOwnednotes(){return this.ownednotes;}

    public void setOwnednotes(GroupSection ownednotes){this.ownednotes=ownednotes;}

    @JsonIgnore
    public int getOwnedSectionId(){
        return this.ownednotes.getMsectionid();
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mnotedata",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<GroupAttachments> mattachments = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<GroupAttachments> getMattachments() {
        return this.mattachments;
    }

    public void setMattachments(Set<GroupAttachments> mattachments) {

        this.mattachments = mattachments;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mhistory",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<GroupNoteHistory> groupNoteHistorySet = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<GroupNoteHistory> getGroupNoteHistorySet(){
        return this.groupNoteHistorySet;
    }

    public void setGroupNoteHistorySet(Set<GroupNoteHistory> groupNoteHistorySet){
        this.groupNoteHistorySet = groupNoteHistorySet;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unreadNotes",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<UnreadNotes> unreadNotesSet = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<UnreadNotes> getUnreadNotesSet(){
        return this.unreadNotesSet;
    }

    public void setUnreadNotesSet(Set<UnreadNotes> unreadNotesSet){
        this.unreadNotesSet = unreadNotesSet;
    }
//getters and setters ignored
}
```

Error log :

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupNotes["ownedSectionId"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupNotes["ownedSectionId"])
```

Kindly let me know what to do, as I am stuck on that error since some time.

Comment: why you have `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"ownedSectionId"})` without to have such property in your class?

Comment: @NikolayRusev : That was the variable error I was getting, so I was trying. I didnt had it before, but I had the same problem. Can you help me with this problem.

Comment: I'm trying to find where can be the problem:)

Comment: @NikolayRusev : If you need any more code or information, please let me know.

Comment: do you have another group notes dto object? if yes, post the code

Comment: @NikolayRusev : Nope, I dont have any other DTO object for GroupNotes.

Comment: in the controller method what is this GroupNotes object with multiple fields like attachCount,noteDate etc?

Comment: @NikolayRusev : Those are the variables in GroupNotes model, I didnt paste them for brevity.

Comment: post them, may be the problem is in these fields

Comment: l'm writing from my phone but try to add @JsonIgnore on the complex getter methods like getUnreadNotes,getAttachments,getNotes history etc. and see what happens. if no error is raised we will know that one of these methods cause the exception

Comment: @NikolayRusev : Ok, I will do that now. No, still the same error, I will do it for GroupCanvas and GroupSection major methods too, but I don't believe this to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think that happens is Jackson tries to serialize all fields in the hierarchy based on getter methods. In some situation `NullPointerException` is thrown in the following method:

```
@JsonIgnore
public int getOwnedSectionId(){
    return this.ownednotes.getMsectionid();
}
```

replace it with the following method:

```
@JsonIgnore
public int getOwnedSectionId(){
    if(this.ownednotes != null)
        return this.ownednotes.getMsectionid();
    return 1;
}
```

I don't have an explanation why jackson tries to serialize it when is market with @JsonIgnore but you can give a try with my proposal

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. But why is JsonIgnore not being honoured?? I will surely mark your answer.

Comment: i'm not sure man. I have to research to tell you why. I have some sigguestions but I'm not sure.  Try to remove @JsonIgnore from the field:

`@JsonIgnore
    public GroupSection getOwnednotes(){return this.ownednotes;}`

Comment: That didn't help. Whenever you have time, please help me understand this. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I would appreciate if anyone tells me either how to fix this error or convert the objects to a DTO objects so they can be transferred.

We use [DozerMapper](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer) at work for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that mapping manually you might want to take a look at [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://blazebit.com/blog/2016/getting-started-with-blaze-persistence-entity-views.html) which can be used to efficiently implement the DTO pattern with JPA. Here a quick code sample how your problem could be solved

First you define your DTO as entity view

```
@EntityView(GroupNotes.class)
public interface GroupNoteView {
    @IdMapping("mnoticesid") int getId();

    String getMnotecolor();
    String getMnotetag();
    String getMnotetext();
    String getNoteDate();
    Timestamp getNoteCreationTime();
    int getAttachCount();
}
```

Next you adapt your DAO to make use of it

```
@Override
public List<GroupNoteView> searchNotesByDays(int days, int mcanvasid) {
    EntityManager entityManager = // get the entity manager from somewhere
    CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf = // factory for query building from Blaze-Persistence
    EntityViewManager evm = // factory for applying entity views on query builders

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -days);
    long daysAgo = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    Timestamp nowMinusDaysAsTimestamp = new Timestamp(daysAgo);

    CriteriaBuilder<GroupNotes> cb = cbf.create(entityManager, GroupNotes.class, "note")
        .where("noteCreationTime").gt(nowMinusDaysAsTimestamp)
        .where("ownednotes.ownedcanvas.mcanvasid").eq(mcanvasid);

    return evm.applySetting(EntityViewSetting.create(GroupNoteView.class), cb)
        .getResultList();
}
```

And finally the calling code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findgroupnotes/{days}/{canvasid}")
public @ResponseBody List<GroupNoteView> findGroupNotesByDays(@PathVariable("days")int days, @PathVariable("canvasid")int canvasid){
    return this.groupNotesService.findGroupNotesByDays(days, canvasid);
}
```